# Variable only storing first letter of select result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a cell that's has a two letter nvarchar as its content, which I want to  save to a simple nvarchar variable, however, only the first letter of the two-letter cell content is being saved with the following code.

```
DECLARE @RC NVARCHAR = (SELECT Value FROM @scoreTable WHERE Metric = 'RC')


-- this returns 'ND' as expected
SELECT Value FROM @scoreTable WHERE Metric = 'RC' 

-- but this returns 'N'! Why?
SELECT @RC
```

I'm totally stumped. How can I get both letters (i.e. all of the content of the cell) to save to the variable `@RC`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the length for character types in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @RC NVARCHAR(255) = (SELECT Value FROM @scoreTable WHERE Metric = 'RC')
```

In SQL Server (but not all other databases), you should *always* use the length with character types.  The default varies by context, so relying on the default length can be quite confusing.